# removeChild after Tweenlite does not really work

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I'd like to remove objects via removeChild after Tweenlite has finished tweening. But it doesn't really work because my objects are still in the DisplayList. I can't figure out the problem so I would be very happy if someone could help me out with this problem. Thanks in advance.:)

```
//TweenLite.to(sndText, .5, {alpha:0, onComplete:removeChild, onCompleteParams:[sndText]});//does not really work; still in DisplayList

TweenLite.to(sndText, .5, {alpha:0});
TweenLite.to(musicText, .5, {alpha:0});
TweenLite.to(sndSlider, .5, {alpha:0});
TweenLite.to(musicSlider, .5, {alpha:0});
TweenLite.to(okBtn, .5, {alpha:0});
TweenLite.to(sndMinus, .5, {alpha:0});
TweenLite.to(sndPlus, .5, {alpha:0});
TweenLite.to(musicMinus, .5, {alpha:0});
TweenLite.to(musicPlus, .5, {alpha:0, onComplete:removeSettings});

//removeChild(sndText); //this works but I don't know why


override public function removeSettings():void {

//removeChild doesn't really work (still in DisplayList) 
removeChild(sndText);
removeChild(musicText);
removeChild(sndSlider);
removeChild(musicSlider);
removeChild(okBtn);
removeChild(sndMinus);
removeChild(sndPlus);
removeChild(musicMinus);
removeChild(musicPlus);

}
```

Comment: Are you able to trace or hit a breakpoint in the removeSettings function to make sure it's actually being called? You'd then also be able to watch each object's parent property to see if it gets set to null after removeChild is called.

Comment: Did u seen any error in the output panel?

Comment: tracing works in the remvoveSettings function. I didn't check the breakpoint-thing so far so I'll examine that. Currently there are no errors in the output panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `TweenLite.killTweensOf` before removing the clip:

```
TweenLite.killTweensOf(sndText);
removeChild(sndText);
```

Comment: killTweensOf didn't do the trick but I got the bug. Actually it was my fault! Accidentally I traced the number of children WHILE tweenlite was tweening my objects. So they still appeared in the display list. I just forgot that tweenlite uses its own tweening engine. I'm such an idiot.:/